# QTreeView setStyleSheet has no effect

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qtreeview, qtstylesheets

I want to set background color of a selected inactive item in a *QTreeView* using style sheet as follows:

```
MyTreeView->setStyleSheet("QTreeView::item:selected:!active { background-color: rgb(150, 180, 220) }");
```

But the code has no effect in the tree view, but the similar code works for *QTableView*.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps yet another Qt style sheets bugs. Have you tried using a different application style (e.g Fusion?)

Comment: Sorry guys. Actually there is nothing wrong in the CSS. It started working later. I have no idea why. But thanks for your time...

Answer (score -1):

rgb(150, 180, 220); you need the semi colon inside too.

Comment: Sorry guys. Actually there is nothing wrong in the CSS. It started working later. I have no idea why. But thanks for your time...

Comment: It usually doesn't work without the semicolon inside the literal. In your case since you were only notifying one attribute it might have been fine, but rule of thumb - use semicolons in there because the compiler won't catch that for you since its part of a string literal.